# How to get dlopen loaded to start rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dlopen

I'm trying to run rails from my root directory (Im using RVM) and I get this message:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': dlopen(~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/pg-0.11.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.3.dylib
```

Anybody knows how to install that missing dependency? tried using

```
brew install dlopen
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're on mac (otherwise you wouldn't use homebrew, right?)

Check these links as they will solve all problems with dependencies on mac (or *nux)

- http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/
- http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/
- http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/

Start with SSL, as the error is pointing in that direction, and use the other links if you get an error with readline or zlib.

As a side note, RVM rubies don't use homebrew libraries as far as I know.

## PLEASE READ!

RVM has moved to http://rvm.io and the instructions that used to be in the links avove are **not valid** for the current version of rvm. So if  you're having a problem like the OP had, look somewhere else!

Comment: These links dont seem to open. Are there alternative sources for this information?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Sagar. It looks like rvm is now hosted on http://rvm.io . I just updated the links to the new locations, but for some odd reason, those 3 pages now show the same content :S.

Comment: Additionally, i get the following erroe 'Unknown subcommand 'rvm_pkg' for autolibs'

When i try a rvm autolibs rvm_pkg

Comment: I just read the page, and it says that the information in there is deprecated. So my answer is not valid for the current version of RVM