# Rails Installation problems (Mac 10.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I just installed ruby using homebrew and performed a gem install of rails.

While it says that rails has been installed, when i type in rails on terminal i get the following output :

```
/Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest/md5.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest/md5.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest/md5.bundle
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rails:19:in `load'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/moveablecode/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any solution to fix these errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get dlopen loaded to start rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214926/how-to-get-dlopen-loaded-to-start-rails)

Comment: What have you tried? do you have the file `/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` ?

Comment: Simone, the links in the answer you posted seem to be broken. Is there an alternative link i can access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use railsinstaller. download it from http://railsinstaller.org/ 
and follow steps from http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac it will more helpful for you.This is easiest way to install rails

Comment: Tried this! Im getting the same errors. If im correct, seems like i dont have some of the dependencies rails requires!

Comment: This resolved my issue! I completely uninstalled ruby rails and rvm (rvm implode) followed the instructions on the link and everything worked fine!